# T SQL - Special order for hierarchy

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some problems with the order of my select and don't know how to fix it.

The hierarchy should look like this:

```
10
100
1001
1003
1004
1007
10010
20
210
2101
220
22100
22101
```

But when I do a usual order by this hierarchy I get it like that:

```
10
20
100
210
220
1001
...
```

Does anyone have an idea how I could get the right order?

Comment: Whats your column DataType?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your column is of a number data type. Convert it to a string like this

```
select * from your_table
order by cast(your_column as varchar(20))
```

Comment: No, they are alredy INT. That's the reason why the order is 10, 20, 100 instead of 10, 100, 1001, (...), 20, 210

Comment: got it the other way around. Fixed now

Answer (score 1):

I a bit stole answer from @juegend
he was write but you must cast to some VARCHAR

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table 
ORDER BY CAST(ID AS VARCHAR)
```

Comment: That looks better, but is still not the solution. Like that I get 10010 before 1003, 1004, etc. I think I need leading zeros

Answer (score 1):

OK, got it

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table 
ORDER BY RIGHT('00000000' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR),8)
```